# Issue compiling Go program when linking to a compiled version of zeromq on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, go, compilation, zeromq

I've compiled ZeroMQ on Mac OSX 10.9.5 in order to then link to a simple Go program using `github.com/pebbe/zmq4`, but I'm getting this error I don't understand or know exactly how to remedy.

```
# github.com/pebbe/zmq4
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libzmq.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libzmq.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_zmq_bind", referenced from:
      __cgo_59814aec404b_C2func_zmq_bind in zmq4.cgo2.o
      __cgo_59814aec404b_Cfunc_zmq_bind in zmq4.cgo2.o
     (maybe you meant: __cgo_59814aec404b_Cfunc_zmq_bind, __cgo_59814aec404b_C2func_zmq_bind )
  "_zmq_close", referenced from:
      __cgo_59814aec404b_C2func_zmq_close in zmq4.cgo2.o
      __cgo_59814aec404b_Cfunc_zmq_close in zmq4.cgo2.o
     (maybe you meant: __cgo_59814aec404b_C2func_zmq_close, 
...
  "_zmq_z85_encode", referenced from:
      __cgo_59814aec404b_Cfunc_zmq_z85_encode in zmq4.cgo2.o
     (maybe you meant: __cgo_59814aec404b_Cfunc_zmq_z85_encode)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think it makes sense that the dylib is made for x86_64 (the Mac) but why Go is trying to link with i386?  How do I control that and make it link differently? or even if it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you build libzmq yourself, configure with `--disable-shared --enable-static` keys. If you use homebrew, uninstall zmq and build the library manually. If you need "fat" universal static library use this script:
https://github.com/drewcrawford/libzmq-ios